# Getting failure when using filemtime() with wp_enqueue_style

Tags: theme-development, cache

I am trying to change the stylesheet file version using the `filemtime()` function with the `wp_enqueue_style` with the following snippet

```
function pro_styles()
{
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/child-style.css', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/child-style.css'), 'all' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pro_styles' );
```

but it is throwing a warning

> Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for.....

While i am sure that the file exists

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's because you're retrieving it via URL, but `filemtime()` requires a path. Use `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead. That returns a path:

```
function pro_styles()
{
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/child-style.css', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() .'/child-style.css'), 'all' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pro_styles' );
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on Jacob Peattie Answer for people that have CSS file in a custom plugin, you can use

```
filemtime( plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)).'plugin-folder/css-file-path.css' )
```

Comment: great, it works!

Comment: Good find! Further, if the file is in your own same plugin folder, `filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'css-file-path.css')` suffices.